# Converting Oracle query to mySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm no expert in DB Admin, I need to edit a query from Oracle to SQL in my Middleware. I am getting the error

> 102: Incorrect syntax near '@P0'

Can anyone help please

below is the query

```
<assign to="/ProcessData/WERCS/SQL">
            select F_PRODUCT, 
            F_PRODUCT_NAME, 
            SUPPLIER
            from T_INTERPHASE 
            where MODIFIED_DATE &gt;= 
                        TO_DATE(?,&apos;yyyymmdd&apos;) 
            and AUTHGRP like &apos;%Mining Services%&apos; 
        </assign>
```

I have been asked to use CONVERT instead of DATE_TO - so I changed query to:

```
<assign to="/ProcessData/WERCS/SQL">
            select F_PRODUCT, 
            F_PRODUCT_NAME, 
            SUPPLIER
                        from T_INTERPHASE 
            where MODIFIED_DATE &gt;= 
                        CONVERT(?,&apos;yyyymmdd&apos;) 
            and AUTHGRP like &apos;%Mining Services%&apos; 
        </assign>
```

Comment: you know that neither of the queries have `@P0`, so none of them are source of the error, right?

Comment: The documentation of `CONVERT()` is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert). But it's not used for date parsing with an arbitrary format, so it's not clear why you're being told to use that. The MySQL function for date parsing is [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL function for parsing a date with a specified format is [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

```
<assign to="/ProcessData/WERCS/SQL">
            select F_PRODUCT, 
            F_PRODUCT_NAME, 
            SUPPLIER
                        from T_INTERPHASE 
            where MODIFIED_DATE &gt;= 
                        STR_TO_DATE(?,&apos;%Y%m%d&apos;) 
            and AUTHGRP like &apos;%Mining Services%&apos; 
        </assign>
```

However, the error referring to `@P0` must be coming from something else.

Comment: Thanks for your help Barmar, that didn't work.  saying STR_DATE is not recognized as a built in function

Comment: It's `STR_TO_DATE` not `STR_DATE`